# Lua spam click until button released then click on xy coord

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I want to be able press and hold my G5 key on Logitech G910 keyboard to move to xy, click then move to another xy, spam click until I release G5 and then have it move to another xy and click once more before ending

```
if (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 5 and GetMKeyState("kb") == 3) then
    MoveMouseTo( 52250, 46464)
    Sleep(math.random(25, 40))
    PressMouseButton(1)
    ReleaseMouseButton(1)
    Sleep(math.random(25, 40))
    MoveMouseTo( 51841, 48832)
    Sleep(360)
    repeat
        PressMouseButton(1)
        Sleep(math.random(25, 40))
        ReleaseMouseButton(1)
        Sleep(math.random(25, 40))
    until "G_RELEASED" and arg == 5
    Sleep(math.random(25, 40))
    MoveMouseTo( 52250, 46464)
    Sleep(math.random(25, 40))
    PressMouseButton(1)
    ReleaseMouseButton(1)
end
```

I got it working up until the point of the G_RELEASED part it will stop spam clicking but will not move on to the next xy, click.

I did try a few other things where the until G_RELEASED bit as well but just resulted in a continuous spam clicking which I couldn't get to stop without restarting the computer

Comment: Replace `until "G_RELEASED" and arg == 5` with `until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5)`

Comment: Its not a mouse button though? its on the keyboard

Comment: Ops.  Sorry.  You should additionally assign some mouse-style action for your keyboard key G5.  For example, you may assign "Back" action to G5 key.  After that you should use `IsMouseButtonPressed(4)` in the "until" statement because the default meaning of mouse button 4 in Windows is "Back".

Comment: Or you may assign a modifier-style action, for example, "LAlt" (left Alt) to G5.  After that you should use `until not IsModifierPressed("LAlt")`.  You can also use any of `lshift/rshift/lalt/ralt/lctrl/rctrl`  Choose the one you usually never use on your keyboard (for me, it is right ctrl).

Comment: Ahh yes seems so simple now, thank you worked perfectly